# How to remove point labels in react-chartjs-2 Line component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am working with the `Line` component from `react-chartjs-2` and having trouble with removing labels on the points of the line.

[Line Graph Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES7pY.png)

Line Options:

```
const chartOptions: DeepPartial<
  CoreChartOptions<"line"> &
    ElementChartOptions<"line"> &
    PluginChartOptions<"line"> &
    DatasetChartOptions<"line"> &
    ScaleChartOptions<"line"> &
    LineControllerChartOptions
> = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: "top" as const,
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 2,
    },
  },
};
```

Line Data:

```
const chartData: ChartData<"line", number[], string> = {
    labels: Object.keys(sampleData),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Score",
        data: Object.values(sampleData).map(
          (val) => Math.round(val * 100) / 100
        ),
        backgroundColor: "#FF6384",
        borderColor: "#FF6384",
        pointRadius: 1,
        borderWidth: 2,
        tension: 0.1,
      } as ChartDataset<"line", number[]>,
    ],
  };
```

Sample data:

```
const sampleData = {
    "2016-08-28": 0.5786274509803921,
    "2016-10-09": -0.5872549019607842,
    "2016-10-10": 0.02058823529411765,
    "2016-11-07": 0.05679738562091504,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the right config to hide data point labels. It was:

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        display: false,
    },
}
```

Found it here for anyone interested: [Chartjs hide data point labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268325/chartjs-hide-data-point-labels)